# How do I configure my Azure app registration and native client to support guest accounts using MSA authenticated through device code flow?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an application that currently authenticates users in an Azure active directory tenant. I have native clients that use MSAL, [device code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code) and an api scope to get a token to use with an ASP.NET Web API application. We also have a web front end that consumes the web api endpoints. We would like to allow external users access to this application. I've added [guest users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/) with personal Microsoft accounts (MSA) to the tenant and they are able to authenticate to the web front end using MSAL.js in an SPA. When these guest users try to authenticate using device code flow I get the error:

**Message: AADSTS165000: Invalid Request: The request did not include the required tokens for the user context. One or more of the user context values (cookies; form fields; headers) were not supplied, every request must include these values and maintain them across a complete single user flow. The request did not return all of the form fields. Failure Reasons:[Token was not provided;]**

Regular users on the tenant authenticate using the device code flow successfully.

- Authority is : [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bmy) tenant id}
- Scope passed for device code is an api scope: api://{my api id}/data.read
- In the app registration the redirect URLs are set to :
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient and
  msal{some id}://auth
- Implicit grant is enabled for Access tokens and Id tokens
- Supported account types is to to single tenant
- Allow public client flows is set to Yes

If I change the authority to use 'common' instead of the tenant id, the guest user can authenticate but then the token I get from the client uses the Microsoft account tenant of 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad and the OID is for that tenant and not the OID of the guest user in my org's tenant

Comment: I replied to a similar question before. see :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494591/onedrive-authentication.The reason for the error was the wrong issuer of the token. You need to log in as a guest user and obtain the authorization code. I recommend you to use auth code flow.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. The native client is on an input constrained device and needs to use device code flow as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code
The user receives a device code which they then enter on another device at https://www.microsoft.com/devicelogin which then prompts the user to enter their authentication information. The user enters their guest user login information and at that point they are redirected to a page with the error described above.